# save string over saved string in core data

Tags: swift, string, indexing, core-data, instance

In my swift code below the code saves an item in core data. The goal is to overwrite that item. I am getting a runtime error at

```
CoreDataHandler.changeName(user: fetchUser!\[indexNumber\], jessica: "jo")
```

[image: pic of core data]

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I don't know how to wrap in the index number. The goal is it to print judo then jo

```
import UIKit;import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var fetchUser: [UserInfo]? = nil
    var indexNumber : Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CoreDataHandler.saveObject2( name:  "judo")
        getText(textNo: indexNumber)
        saveTheItem()
      
    }

    @objc func saveTheItem(){
        
        CoreDataHandler.changeName(user: fetchUser![indexNumber], jessica: "jo")
    }
    func getText(textNo:Int) {
        // first check the array bounds
        let info = helpText.shareInstance.fetchText()
    
        if info.count > textNo {
            

            
            
            if let imageData = info[textNo].name
            {
                print(imageData)
                
            } else {
                // no data
                print("data is empty Textss")
            }
        } else {
            // image number is greater than array bounds
            print("you are asking out of bounds")
        }
    }
    
}

class CoreDataHandler : NSManagedObject {
    
    class func saveObject2( name: String) -> Bool {
        let context = getContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UserInfo", in: context)
        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        
        
        managedObject.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        
        
        do{
            try context.save()
            return true
        }
        catch {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{
        let appD = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appD.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    class func changeName(user: UserInfo,jessica : String) -> Bool
    {
        
        let context = getContext()
        
        user.name = jessica
        
        
        
        print(jessica)
        do{
            
            try context.save()
            return true
        }
        catch{
            return false
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
}

class helpText: UIViewController{
    private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    static let shareInstance = helpText()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    func saveName(data: String) {
        let imageInstance = UserInfo(context: context)
        imageInstance.name = data
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchText() -> [UserInfo] {
        
        
        var fetchingImage = [UserInfo]()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "UserInfo")
        
        do {
            
            fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [UserInfo]
        } catch {
            print("Error while fetching the image")
        }
        
        return fetchingImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No offense but your code is a mess.

And there is a big misunderstanding. Core Data records are unordered, there is no index. To update a record you have to fetch it by a known attribute, in your example by **name**, update it and save it back.

This is a simple method to do that. It searches for a record with the given `name`. If there is one, update the attribute with `newName` and save the record.

The code assumes that there is a `NSManagedObject` subclass `UserInfo` with implemented class method `fetchRequest`.

```
func changeName(_ name: String, to newName: String) {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request : NSFetchRequest<UserInfo> = UserInfo.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
    do {
        let records = try context.fetch(request)
        guard let foundRecord = records.first else { return }
        foundRecord.name = newName
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Regarding your confusing code:

Create `CoreDataHandler` as singleton (and it **must not** be a subclass of `NSManagedObject`). Move the Core Data related code from AppDelegate and the methods to read and write in this class.

Comment: Thanks for your help I don't know how to create coreDataHandeler as a singleton

Comment: Also what do I put in in   CoreDataHandler.changeName()

Comment: Please read for example [this article](https://medium.com/@maddy.lucky4u/swift-4-core-data-part-3-creating-a-singleton-core-data-refactoring-insert-update-delete-9811af2fcf75)